# Parse number out of field and put in it's own column

Tags: string, parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data that looks like the following

```
   Public Name       | Internal Name |
_____________________|_______________|
Name of object1 (#1) |    1345312    |
Name of object2 (#2) |    1387924    | 
..
object2000 (#2000)   |    6875238    |
```

And I'm hoping to parse out the (#*) into it's own column. To look like below

```
Public Number |    Public Name   | Internal Name |
______________|__________________|_______________|
     (#1)     | Name of object1  |    1345312    |
     (#2)     | Name of object2  |    1387924    | 
..
     (#2000)  |    object2000    |    6875238    |
```

I have absolutely no idea how I would begin to do this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  [Public Number] = CASE WHEN [Public Name] LIKE '%(#%' THEN
    SUBSTRING([Public Name], CHARINDEX('(', [Public Name]), 255)
    ELSE '' END,
  [New Public Name] = CASE WHEN [Public Name] LIKE '%(#%' THEN
    RTRIM(LEFT([Public Name], CHARINDEX('(', [Public Name])-1))
    ELSE [Public Name] END,
  [Internal Name]
FROM dbo.table;
```

Comment: I may have related my information poorly. The above is the table as it currently stands. The below is what I would like the SELECT statement to be. I do not want to alter the data. So I wouldn't need the update statement you provided, correct?

Comment: @mhopkins321 that's right. You should update your question to stop talking about "its own column" because to most people that means an update.

Comment: You have 3 arguments in the "LEFT" command. I'm getting an error that I can only have 2. Bug or feature?

Comment: I would attempt to fix this myself but I'm very ignorant when it comes to string parsing. I am now getting this error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` Looks like the 1 may have been important?

Comment: @mhopkins321 well do you have values in the table that *don't* contain `(#some number)`? What do you want displayed in that column in that case?

Comment: Ah I see. There are several that don't contain a public number, and in those cases I suppose nothing should be in the "public number" column.